# How to output WooCommerce product attributes as <UL>?

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes

I am using Woocommerce for Wordpress, and trying to change the way product attribute is displayed (product-attribute.php). As you can see, the values are outputted in a td and each item is separated by a comma, but I need them in an unordered list instead, with each item into a separate li. 
Can you help me with this, please?

```
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :

    if ( empty( $attribute['is_visible'] ) || ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] && ! taxonomy_exists( $attribute['name'] ) ) )
    continue;
?>  
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute->get_name() ); ?></th>
    <?php
        if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

            $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
            foreach ( $values as $value ) :
                echo '<td>'; 
                echo $value;
                echo '</td>';
            endforeach;
        } else {

            $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
            foreach ( $values as $value ) :
                echo '<td>'; 
                echo $value;
                echo '</td>';
            endforeach;
        }
    ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Right now I have

```
<td>item1, item2, item3</td>
```

but ideally, what I need is

```
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
```

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: you are modifying the `product-attribute.php` correct? do u want all attributes including weight and dimensions?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I am trying to modify the product-attribute.php :) I only want to modify the display for custom attributes.

Comment: one more question before posting my answer you just need the code above in the `product-attribute.php` and you removed everything else in there right? or u want to keep the default woocommerce code and just modify it ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need :) And thank you for helping! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :

    if ( empty( $attribute['is_visible'] ) || ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] && ! taxonomy_exists( $attribute['name'] ) ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    ?>  

    <p><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute->get_name() ); ?></p>
    <?php
    if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

        $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
        foreach ( $values as $value ) :
            echo '<li>';
            echo $value;
            echo '</li>';
        endforeach;
    } else {

        $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
        foreach ( $values as $value ) :
            echo '<li>';
            echo $value;
            echo '</li>';
        endforeach;
    }
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

i just replaces the `<td>` in your code with `<li>` and added the `<ul>` instead of `<tr>` also i modified the `<th>`  to `<p>`

Comment: What I get is '<ul><p>Name</p><li>item1, item2, item3</li></ul>' but I'm trying to have each item into a <li> instead of separated by a comma. Do you know how to achieve this? Thanks again :D

Comment: @Sebbie you are getting this result?  as am getting them on local maching as `<ul><p>Size</p> <li>L</li> <li>M</li></ul>`

Comment: can you please add after `$values =` `var_dump( $values ); ` and post the result

Comment: thank you so much, it worked :) And I realize that the changes were simple, I guess I'm just an exhausted noob and need to call it a day ahaha! You have been my savior today, thank you so much!!!